# Calculating Speed of Android device in Navigation mode using ArcGIS Runtime SDK?

Tags: routing, android, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android, navigation

I am working on a Navigation App and I am using ArcGIS runtime sdk for this. It looks pretty straight forward and I was able to create a simple app. Now I want to calculate the speed of the device while navigating. I was wondering if that is possible or not as I did not find anything in this regard in ArcGIS documentation.

Answer (score 1):

we can use the inbuilt method `loc.getSpeed()` method inside the `onLocationChanged(Location loc) method of LocationListener.` below is the code block:

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public MyLocationListener() {
        super();
    }


    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc == null)
            return;
        boolean zoomToMe = (mLocation == null) ? true : false;
        mLocation = new Point(loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude());
        if (zoomToMe) {
            Point p = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(mLocation, egs, wm);
            map.zoomToResolution(p, 20.0);
            Toast.makeText(RoutingSample.this,Float.toString(loc.getSpeed()) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need distance traveled over time whereby the device GPS will be most accurate for distance traveled. You can use the ArcGIS Android `LocationDisplayManager.getLocationListener()` to get an Android `LocationListener` to receive notification of when location has changed.  You can also get direct access to the current `Location` with `LocationDisplayManager.getLocation()`.

Comment: Thanks mate but I figured it out and it is even easier than this. we can use the inbuilt method loc.getSpeed() method inside the onLocationChanged(Location loc) method of LocationListener.